# List of custom controls

Tags: winforms, list, controls, devexpress

I want to display a list of custom controls. How do I select them and have a vertical scrollbar?

Any ideas of what control to use? ([Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) or [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Home/Mission.xml).)

Comment: Where do you want to display the list? What do you mean by "selecting" the controls? What is it that you are trying to do? Please edit the question to include more details about what you want to do.

Comment: i want to select the custom controls as i select a cell in a grid, just the whole control. i want to display the list somewhere, doesn;t matter what control to use, panel, listbox, and so on. just to be able to display the list of custom controls, to be able to select one, and to have scroll bar.

Comment: Have you tried Panel or FlowLayouPanel

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [XtraLayoutControl](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Layout/).  It allows the end-user to customize the form's layout in runtime, preserve and load it later.  Also, it allows the end-user to select a control when the layotControl is in the customization mode.